# SQL Query within Excel VBA macro not displaying aggregated function?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

When running a SQL code to select a Name and Sum (Policies), everything works fine, as expected (a).

However, when adding Code, Name, and Sum (Policies,), the policies do not appear!  (b).

What am I doing wrong, and how do I get this to work?

a. Works:

```vb
Sub Macro1()
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim sql As String
Dim strConnection As String

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
 "Data Source=C:\Users\gorny\OneDrive\Documents\Brown Brothers    Harriman\Macros\VBA Data.accdb;"

cn.Open strConnection

 sql = "SELECT Name, Sum([Policy Count]) As Policies" & _
    " FROM Profiles " & _
    " GROUP BY Name " & _
    " Having Count([# of Families - All Forms])>1 " & _
    " Order By Name Asc"

Set rs = cn.Execute(sql)

Do Until rs.EOF
Debug.Print rs.Fields(0); " "; CStr(rs.Fields(1))
rs.MoveNext
Loop

End Sub
```

Result, as expected:

```vb
Adam Miller Agency, LLC 11

Gary Gorny Agency, LLC 80

Irina Gornaya Agency 313

Ovsey Dybner Agency 157

Thomas Edison Agency 225

Wonderful Agency 23
```

(b) Adding code eliminates the sum of policies! Why, and how to fix?

```vb
Sub Macro1()
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim sql As String
Dim strConnection As String

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
 "Data Source=C:\Users\gorny\OneDrive\Documents\Brown Brothers    Harriman\Macros\VBA Data.accdb;"

cn.Open strConnection

 sql = "SELECT Code, Name, Sum([Policy Count]) As Policies" & _
    " FROM Profiles " & _
    " GROUP BY Code, Name " & _
    " Having Count([# of Families - All Forms])>1 " & _
    " Order By Name Asc"

Set rs = cn.Execute(sql)

Do Until rs.EOF
Debug.Print rs.Fields(0); " "; CStr(rs.Fields(1))
rs.MoveNext
Loop

End Sub
```

Where are my sum of policies?

```vb
5000076 Adam Miller Agency, LLC

5000077 Gary Gorny Agency, LLC

5000078 Irina Gornaya Agency

5000079 Ovsey Dybner Agency

5000080 Thomas Edison Agency

5000081 Wonderful Agency
```

Comment: I don't see them being printed by your `Debug.Print` statement......

Comment: You're just missing the 3rd field (index 2); Debug.Print rs.Fields(0); " "; CStr(rs.Fields(1)); " "; CStr(rs.Fields(2))

Comment: That worked, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Looping over the fields of the recordset will ensure that you always print all the values.  Alternately, `Recordset.getString` returns a string will all the records.

```
Debug.Print "Print Recordset Column Headers And Values"
Dim c As Long
For c = 0 To rs.Fields.count - 1
    Debug.Print rs.Fields(c).Name,
Next

Do Until rs.EOF
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print String(50, "-")
    For c = 0 To rs.Fields.count - 1
        Debug.Print rs.Fields(c).value,
    Next

    rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.MoveFirst
Debug.Print String(5, vbNewLine)
Debug.Print "Use getString to Print Recordset Values"
Debug.Print String(50, "-")
Debug.Print rs.getString
```

### Results

[image]